# Is storing uploaded image file by date a good option?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it a good option to store uploaded images, for a website that takes images of people's items, in a directories by date? E.G: A file uploaded today would be stored SOMEDIRPATH/2011/12/21/GUID.img - I don't want to overload a directory with a bunch of images and I want to plan for a site where any number of people could be uploading images. This is on a Windows NTFS file system.

Also note that I will save the path in the database.

I have checked and this is not a duplicate question. No answers exist for this question.

Comment: Are you asking if there is a technical advantage to storing the files in a directory structure like so?

Comment: Yes or if there were any better methods.

Comment: Why not save the image in the database as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally consider this a good idea. I use it and have never had a problem with it.

One of concerns may be the security, since you are making it possible to predict the physical path of the file on the server, but since it's an image, not a credit card info, and you have a well-configured web server, that prohibits directory browsing, you are fine with the approach.

Comment: That was my thinking as well. I'm using ASP.NET which defaults to turning off directory browsing.

Comment: Abstraction can also be added in code to refer to virtual paths for the image fetching.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a good idea. And depending on how many files you are going to receive a day, breaking it down into more subfolders (by hour and maybe even minute) is a good idea.

For look ups, you would still want to store the date/time on a database. Do not rely on your folder structure for this.

Comment: I think he is saving that info in a database, but doing this to make sure that all the images the database refers to don't end up in one folder.

Comment: He doesn't explicitly state that he is saving the date to the db. I just want him to know that he should still store the date in the database and not use the path as a way of crafting the date.

Answer (score 0):

That depends- are you going to be retrieving the images primarily by date?  If not (for instance, if I upload abcdefg.jpg and want to retrieve it later), you are going to need to store not only the images name but the date I uploaded it in a database somewhere in order to look it up later.

On the other hand, if you are going to process a whole bunch of images as a batch at the end of the day, then this might be a reasonable upload storage strategy.

Comment: This isn't going to be a batch process. I'll update my details to explain this but I am going to store the path in the database as well.

Answer (score 0):

Seems good to me, Windows can't handle a folder with more than 8000 images in it so making sure you avoid scenarios of explosion is important.  I tend to save mine with a little more logic as to who owns it and whatnot but I don't see why saving it by date would not work - although maybe your SOMEDIRPATH already includes similar logic.

Comment: Can you provide documentation about this 8000 file limit?  Everything I read seems to suggest that the right number is significantly larger.

Comment: @Travis J where did you hear that windows cannot handle a folder with more than 8k images? Are you referring specifically to the performance of the explorer application accessing a folder with more than 8k images? NTFS is capable of (2^32 - 1 = 4.294.967.295 files) - http://superuser.com/a/6398

Comment: This came from a MSDN article, sorry I do not have a link and you may choose to question the information if you wish.

Comment: I know for a fact that Windows can handle more than 8000 files in a single directory. It may note be able to cache the images/thumbnails (perhaps this is what Travis is talking about), but it can certainly display the files in Details view. The performance starts to seriously degrade, which is a good reason to break up the directory structure by date/time.

Comment: Yes, you can put them in there, but it is the indexing which starts to break I believe.  Sorry for the vagueness of "handle".  A simple test would be to try it yourself!  for(int i = 0; i < 8000; i++){saveImageToLocation(i);} ShowImageFromLocation(5600);  *try at your own risk*